# How do I use the Facebook Graph API to grab a specific data field from a user?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, parameters

I am struggling to use the Graph Api efficiently.

After hitting the facebook server for me/friends and parsing all friend ID'd into a dictionary (I'm developing in Objective C for the Iphone), I want to get certain info about each friend.

Let's go with a classical example of collecting all of my friends' birthdays.  Note: I have been granted the friends_birthday permission.

The following code uses the oAuth2Test Framework:

```
while ((friend_list = (NSDictionary *)[enumerator nextObject])) {
    //NSString *name = (NSString *)[friend_list objectForKey:@"name"];
                NSString *idd = (NSString *)[friend_list objectForKey:@"name"];

    //The following line would return this users birthday along with all the other information the user is allowed to see/has granted permission for.

    FbGraphResponse *fb2_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphGet:idd withGetVars:nil];
}
```

How would I use a dictionary as the parameter for "withGetVars" to only pull the birthday for each user?

Answer (score 0):

It's simple trick to get the profile of a specific person. Instead of passing `me/feed` pass the specific person ID as eg. `1234567/feed`, you will get his profile details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following graph call using the `fields=birthday` parameter:

```
me/friends?fields=id,name,birthday
```